# For a function satisfying $xf''(x) + 3x(f'(x))^2 = 1 -e^{-x}$ which among the following is correct .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maxima-minima

Given a function $f$ satisfies the equation

$xf''(x) + 3x(f'(x))^2  = 1 -e^{-x}$

then

(a)$f$ has a minimum at $x = a\ne 0$

(b)$f$ has a minimum at $x =2$

(c)$f$ has maximum or minimum at $x = 0$

(d) If $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ then 
$f(x) \le Ax^2$ for all $x \ge 0$ and $A > 0$

So, here is what I did

$f'(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1 - e^{-x} - xf''(x)}{3x}}$, when $x \ne 0$

Since range of $\sqrt{x}$ is $[0, \infty)$,

$f(x)$ is monotonically increasing for $x \ne 0$.

So, clearly option (a) and (b) are False

But I am clueless on how to  tackle the case when $x =0$

and I have no idea how to prove\disprove option (d)

Can anyone help me here ?

Thank you.

Comment: What if $f'(x) = 0$?

Comment: Your arguments are invalid. Why did you take the positive square root when you solved the equation for $f'(x)$? (This is like saying that any real number $t$ is $\geq 0$ since $t =\sqrt {t^{2}}$).

Comment: Without giving initial conditions, there is nothing you can say about local extrema. There is nothing preventing you from setting $f'(0)=1$ and $f'(2)=-1$, for example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yes sir, you are correct it is a mistake the correct equation should be $\left|f'(x)\right|$, but then no information can be obtained regarding the nature of function directly .

Answer (score 1):

Note that $c(x)=\frac{1-e^{-x}}x$ can be extended to a smooth function by setting $c(0)=1$. Then $f''(x)+3f'(x)^2=c(x)$ is a smooth ODE on the domain $\Bbb R^2$, without any singularities.

The DE can be considered a Riccati equation for $f'$. Set $g=e^{3f}$, then $f'=\frac{g'}{3g}$, and $g$ as a monotonous transformation has the same local extrema as $f$. The differential equation for $g$ is a linear second order DE
$$
g''(x)=3c(x)g(x).
$$
In both formulations, the full range of initial conditions is available at $x=0$ or $x=2$, so that there is nothing that can force $f$ to have an extremum there.

As $0< c(x)\le 1$ for $x\ge 0$, the growth of any solution $g$ is limited by a multiple of $e^{\sqrt3 x}$, which gives a linear bound for $f$. Combined with the local quadratic growth under the initial conditions $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, this results in a global quadratic bound.